# Mongoose Changing Schema Format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We're rapidly developing an application that's using Mongoose, and our schema's are changing often. I can't seem to figure out the proper way to update a schema for existing documents, without blowing them away and completely re-recreating them from scratch.

I came across http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add, which looks to be right. There's little to no documentation on how to actually implement this, making it very hard for someone who is new to MongoDB.

I simply want to add a new field called enabled. My schema definition is:

```
var sweepstakesSchema = new Schema({
    client_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Client',
        index: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Sweepstakes',
    },
    design: {
        images: {
            type: [],
            default: []
        },
        elements: {
            type: [],
            default: []
        }
    },
    enabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    schedule: {
        start: {
            type: Date, 
            default: Date.now
        },
        end: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    },
    submissions: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's nothing built into Mongoose regarding migrating existing documents to comply with a schema change.  You need to do that in your own code, as needed.  In a case like the new `enabled` field, it's probably cleanest to write your code so that it treats a missing `enabled` field as if it was set to `false` so you don't have to touch the existing docs.

As far as the schema change itself, you just update your `Schema` definition as you've shown, but changes like new fields with `default` values will only affect new documents going forward.

Comment: *but changes like new fields with default values will only affect new documents going forward.* - I guess it also affects updated documents right ? (not only new)

Comment: @Michael Not really, no. Adding new fields with a default value will make those fields appear in the mongoose instances of existing docs, but it won't actually add the field to existing docs, even if you call `save` on them.

Comment: So saving a document which previously did not have field `x` after i've added `x` to the schema with default value will not update the document with `x` ? I don't understand this choice of design, is this documented somewhere ? Thanks

Comment: @Michael Correct. I don't know if it's documented anywhere, but that's what happens when I try it.

Comment: @Michael A lot of methods are pretty much just a passthough to the native mongodb driver (`schema.update` for instance). `find` is among those.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to write something that goes through the documents and adds the field rather than add a hard-coded patch every time you changed the schema?

Answer (score 23):

Considering your Mongoose model name as `sweepstakesModel`,
this code would add `enabled` field with boolean value `false` to all the pre-existing documents in your collection:

```js
db.sweepstakesModel.find( { enabled : { $exists : false } } ).forEach(
    function (doc) {
        doc.enabled = false;
        db.sweepstakesModel.save(doc);
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I was also searching for something like migrations, but didn't find it. As an alternative you could use defaults. If a key has a default and the key doesn't exist, it will use the default.

[Mongoose Defaults](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/defaults.html)

> Default values are applied when the document skeleton is constructed. This means that if you create a new document (new MyModel) or if you find an existing document (MyModel.findById), both will have defaults provided that a certain key is missing.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue, and found that using `findOneAndUpdate()` rather than calling `save` allowed us to update the schema file, without having to delete all the old documents first.

I can post a code snippet if requested.

Answer (score 2):

You might use mongo shell to update the existing documents in a specific collection

```
db.SweeptakesModel.update({}, {$set: {"enabled": false}}, {upsert:false, multi:true})
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement of having to add to an existing schema when building an app with Node, and only found this (long ago posted) query to help.

The schema I added to by introducing the line in the original description of the schema and then running something similar to the following line, just the once, to update existing records:

```
myModelObject.updateMany( { enabled : { $exists : false } }, { enabled : false } )
```

'updateMany' being the function I wanted to mention here.

Answer (score 0):

just addition to what Vickar was suggesting, here Mongoose Example written on Javascript (Nodejs):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const SweeptakesModel = mongoose.model(Constants.SWEEPTAKES,sweepstakesSchema);
SweeptakesModel.find( { enabled : { $exists : false } }).then(
function(doc){
       doc.enabled = false;
       doc.save();
    }
)
```