# Mongoose - Querying a collection for a new property with a default value without having to resave every element

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

We recently added a new property to one of our Mongoose schemas that defines takes a String with an enum validator and a default value. We now need to query for documents using that property but it isn't set for pre-existing documents until after the query happens. Is there any way to get around this without having to re-save every document in that collection that existed before this change, or if not is there a best practice for how to do that cleanly?

The new property:

```
sales_category: {
    type: String, 
    required: true,
    enum: ["Prospect", "Subscriber", "Activated Trial", "Expired Subscriber", "Expired Free Trial"],
    default: "Prospect"
}
```

The query:

```
Account.find({sales_category: "Prospect"}).populate("account_holder").exec(function(err, accounts) {
```

---

Edit: I just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/14288276/8324 which seems to imply that there is no clean way to do this, the suggestion to leave it as it is and just invert any query for {sales_category: "Prospect"} to a query for not any of the other categories seems like the best solution provided the enum never changes. I'm not sure if we can guarantee that it in this use case though so I think I might end up falling back to the "re-save everything" solution, even if it doesn't feel great.

I'll leave this open for now in case someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an [OR](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-or) conditional with an [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator?

```
Account.find().or([{sales_category: "Prospect"}, { sales_category: { $exists: false }}]).populate("account_holder").exec(function(err, accounts) {...});
```

One note: this doesn't use an index which would only be a concern if this is used on a large collection.